Estimating the "final" strength of a kid
The short answer is of course "You can't". There are too many variables (e.g. the amount of special training). Also, ratings are not reliable, if even existent (looking at the current kid championship of my town, 50% of U10s had one and only the strongest of U8s).
Still, I have 40 years of experience training children and would say without any doubt that one of my chess kids will be stronger than me in ten years.
Can you suggest a test that even for beginners might give some hint of their talent?

related: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2358/how-to-gauge-someones-chess-strength-quickly


Can you suggest a test that even for beginners might give some hint of their talent?

The obvious one is how quickly they can do a knight's tour.

I think this will give a better hint of the kids' geometric skills than of their chess skills.

An (I think even more obvious) alternative to Brian's suggestion I just remembered: Memorizing a random chess position from the opening.

Give them puzzles like Mate in 3 and see how well they can visualize moves out loud without making the moves on the board. When I was a kid I knew I wouldn't be a chess star because I couldn't visualize to save my life.

(headscratch) Being able to visualize is great for your chess, alas, I could never properly visualize (or calculate) and still went to be a FM...

@HaukeReddmann your calculation ability must still be at a certain level to reach FM!
